# Caching a web page Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a unity project where on startup it is suppose to display and ask the user to accept the terms and conditions. That part i can take care of but, later if the user wants to check on the terms and condition he should be able to click on it and open it in the game itself. This should work without the internet connection too. I saw something that Application.temporaryCachePath. Is that what i am looking for? Or is there an other way to cache the web page. Working on IOS.

Comment: This isn't caching, caching by definition may discard stored information under certain circumstances. What you need is to download the TOS file to the user documents (or any writable) folder.

Comment: makes sense. How would i open that in the browser then?

Comment: Any decent web view (like UIWebView) is able to open and show files from a local path/file.